# Installing memsql cluster on different ec2 instances as nodes # memsql

Tags: amazon-ec2, singlestore

I am trying to form memsql cluster with 3 ec2 instances using memsql ops By adding hosts. Its showing me the following error "The primary MemSQL Ops agent is using a non-standard install directory for MemSQL. If desired, edit each agent to modify their install directory." I have installed memsql using docker on mac as shown in the guide.

I am sorry if I have done something stupid, i am completely alien to this and trying to learn

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know you solved the problem, but in case any else has questions, our documentation for EC2 is here: http://docs.memsql.com/latest/setup/setup_cloud/.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is the same question going on in our chat line.
in general we recommend using cloud.memsql.com for EC2